# Properties must be a 'array' type, but the final value was: 'null' in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm sending a field of array in `multipart/form-data` form to server, but when I call the variable in that array, it gives me an error.

**Code**

```
MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multiContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
```

```
string email = "mail@example.com";
string firstName = "Andrie";
string lastName = "Tarkovsky";

var fields = "[{\"propertyName\": \"email\", \"propertyValue\": " + email + ", \"propertyLabel\": \"Email\"}, {\"propertyName\": \"firstName\", \"propertyValue\": " + firstName + ", \"propertyLabel\": \"First Name\"}, {\"propertyName\": \"lastName\", \"propertyValue\": " + lastName + ", \"propertyLabel\": \"Last Name\"}]";

multiContent.Add(new StringContent(fields), "properties");
```

**Error**

```
"\"properties must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `\\\"[{\\\"propertyName\\\": \\\"email\\\", \\\"propertyValue\\\": mail@example.com, \\\"propertyLabel\\\": \\\"Email\\\"}, {\\\"propertyName\\\": \\\"firstName\\\", \\\"propertyValue\\\": Andrie, \\\"propertyLabel\\\": \\\"First Name\\\"}, {\\\"propertyName\\\": \\\"lastName\\\", \\\"propertyValue\\\": Tarkovsky, \\\"propertyLabel\\\": \\\"Last Name\\\"}]\\\"`).\\n If \\\"null\\\" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`\""
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share the type of "multiContent"

Comment: You need to add more code please, for example the type of `multiContent`.  Also the `field` property looks more like JSON to me?

Comment: added above, kindly have a look.. thanks

Comment: "it gives me an error" - who is "it"?  Is it a compiler error?  An exception?  An error in the response from the server?

Comment: @Jason server response

Comment: thanks to all, i resovled it.. used `\"" + email + "\"` instead of `" + email + "`

Comment: You should not be trying to create JSON manually.

Comment: yes yes.. that's what I'm doing wrong.. it was basically a work around.. should I post new question or ask here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [@jimenemex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67946282/14515147) and [@colex-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67964968/14515147) solution, I solved it.

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicObject
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

List<Item> Obj = new List<Item>();
List<DynamicObject> Objs = new List<DynamicObject>();

foreach (var p in value.ToList())
{
    Objs.Add(new DynamicObject { PropertyName = p.name, PropertyValue = p.value });
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Objs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be trying to create JSON manually.

If you don't have a concrete class for these variables that is an object then create an anonymous one and then you can use [Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) to convert the object into JSON.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

// string email = "mail@example.com";
// string firstName = "Andrie";
// string lastName = "Tarkovsky";

var obj = new 
{
    email = "mail@example.com",
    firstName = "Andrie",
    lastName = "Tarkovsky"
};

multiContent.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)), "properties");
```

If they are 'dynamic' values, then create an object that represents each value.

```
public class DynamicObject
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

List<DynamicObject> objs = new List<DyanmicObject>(); // Or however you have the list

// Add to the list

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs);
```

Comment: basically they are dynamic fields e.g email, firstName, lastName.. the requirment is I've to send them to server like this `[{"propertyName": item.name, "propertyValue": item.Value}];` where `item.name` is  `email, firstName, lastName`..

Comment: earlier I tried this `Value.ToList().Select(item => new { item.name, item.Value }).ToList();` but the only problem is that it create an object like this `[{"name": item.name, "Value": item.Value}]`, and I want like this `[{"propertyName": item.name, "propertyValue": item.Value}]`

Comment: **Note:** `email, firstName, lastName` are dynamic, could be less or more, I'm getting them from server.

Comment: Sir, I already created class which has `name, value, label` is defined.. the `item.name` contains the name of the dynamic fields e.g. `email, firstName, lastName`, and `item.value` stores it values and `item.label` stores the label of the fields.

Comment: now I just want to know how I send the data like this to server `[{"propertyName": item.name, "propertyValue": item.Value}];`

Comment: I tried this `Value.ToList().Select(item => new { item.name, item.Value }).ToList();`, but It created an object like this `[{"name": item.name, "Value": item.Value}]`

Comment: Try serializing the `DynamicObject` that's above created.

Comment: yes I'm serializing too. snippet from my code `var fields = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);`

Answer (score 2):

Jimenemex's code should work as expected .

Just populate the data in `objs` and Serialize it into json then send to server .

```
public class Item
{
    public string propertyName{ get; set; }
    public string propertyValue{ get; set;}
}

List<Item> objs = new List<Item>();
foreach (var p in item.GetType().GetProperties()) {
   objs.Add(new DynamicObject { propertyName = p.Name, propertyValue =(string)p.GetValue(item) });
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs);
multiContent.Add(new StringContent(json), "properties");
```

Comment: thanks for response, but as I mentioned the in the comments above, I don't know how many fields there are (they are dynamic).. I get them from `public class Item {}`

Comment: `objs.Add(new Item { propertyName = Item.name, propertyValue = item.value });` I want to do something like this.. how could I achieve this?.. thanks

Comment: Do you mean the `Item` class is dynamic ? We can't know its fields ?

Comment: kindly look above in Update section.. is this you are asking for?

Comment: I think you can use ` reflection` to obtain dynamic property name and its value .

Comment: I'm just stuck in this small part

Comment: one question, why you didn't add `public string name { get; set; } public string value { get; set; }` in `Item` ?

Comment: Because we need to Serialize  `Item ` into json string as the format you provided , the `Item ` class should have two properties named `propertyValue` and `propertyName` .

Comment: `item.GetType().GetProperties()` return error, so I used `objs.GetType().GetProperties()`, now it isn't returning error

Comment: `DynamicObject` says that `DynamicObject.DynamicObject()` is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: `DynamicObject does not contain definition for  propertyName`

Comment: when I try to run the program it throw and error `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`